# file:/// url doesn't work in FormData [React Native]

Tags: ios, react-native, form-data

In my react-native app when I take a picture using react-native-vision-camera or resize an image via expo-image-manipulator, I got the following url for the final file/image:

```
file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/CB881575-5B7D-4B1D-A016-CF6A4F025AB4/Library/Caches/ImageManipulator/F1233844-82D9-4281-9865-7B382F3F0F84.jpg
```

Then I create a FormData to upload the source via axios:

```
  formData.append(name, {
    uri: uri.replace("file://", ""),
    type: "image/png",
    name: "filename.png",
  });
```

Note that I replace file:// in the url, as many answers both here and on GitHub said.

Finally:

```
  axios.post(url, formData, {
    headers: {
      Authorization: "Token ...",
      "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
    },
    transformRequest: (formData) => formData,
  });
```

And it doesn't work, the image isn't uploaded on the backed, if I try to print the form data too there's no images inside.

Note: both image/png or image/jpg don't work.

Does someone have had the same issue?
Thank you